# YAML for Azure CLI

Tags: rancher

how I can use Azure CLI in the yaml script, I need to create the yaml template to deploy the Azure AKS to run that template form rancher

any examples how to run Azure CLI from yaml ?

or is it possible to kick of the ansible playbook from rancher ?

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible to use the yaml format by using azure ClI.
I leave you an example below:

actions:

- action: "Azure Cli"
  type: "AZURE_CLI"
  setup_commands:

  - "apt-get update && apt-get -y install git"
    commands:
  - "az webapp list"
    shell: "SH"
    integration_hash: "5ed4fe6446e03e110be748d5"